# "once I receive it" vs. "once received"

Tags: phrases

What is the difference between **once I receive it** and **once received**?

Ex.

1. I will send the picture to you once I receive it from John.
2. I will send the picture to you once received.

Comment: Both are grammatical. There's no difference in meaning.

Comment: The second doesn't say where you received it from. 1. is the same as: "I will sent the picture to you once received ***from John***."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only difference is that the first sentence makes it explicitly clear who is expected to receive the picture from whom.

The second sentence does not state that explicitly, but only assures the listener that the speaker will send him the picture once "someone" receives the picture from "someone". For instance, your second sentence *could* imply the following, among many other possibilities:

> I will send the picture to you once received (by my assistant from John's secretary).

Note though, that the parenthesized part is only used to explain my point. A more natural phrasing of that sentence would be:

> I will send you the picture once my assistant receives it from John's secretary.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add that example 1 is in the active voice and example 2 is in the passive voice (hence the unspoken by-phrase, "once received (by...)."